# How to format the output error so that server is not listed twice?

Tags: powershell, cmd

I have this script:

```
$params = '/r', '/f',
          '/t', '0',
          '/d', 'p:0:0',
          '/c', 'PlannedRestart'

$servers | ForEach-Object {
    $output = & shutdown.exe /m "\\${_}" @params 2>&1
    if ($LastExitCode -eq 0) {
        "{0}`tRestarted" -f $_
    } else {
        "{0}`tRestart failed:`t{1}" -f $_, $output
    }
} | Set-Content '.\RestartServers_LOG.txt'
```

it prints like this when it fails:

> server1 Restart failed:server1:error

i want it to print:

> server1 Restart failed:error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the hostname always appears at the beginning of the captured output you can remove it with a simple replacement, e.g. like this:

```
"{0}`tRestart failed:`t{1}" -f $_, ($output -replace "^${_}:")
```

If it can appear at different locations in the output string you need to provide a more complete output example.

Comment: perfect! it prints as i need

Comment: Another way would be `($output -replace '.*:')` to remove everything before and including the COLON.

Comment: @lit `-replace '.*:'` would remove everything up to and including the *last* colon in the string. ITYM `-replace '.*?:'` or (better) `-replace '[^:]*:'`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - Yes, you are right. The default mode for regex is to be greedy.

Comment: @lit yes i was waiting for cooldown timer to let me accept :)